# setTimeout does not wait for specified number of milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, onkeyup

I would like to have a form triggering submit after a few seconds of inactivity (using the `onKeyup` event).

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="getJSONForm">
            <textarea rows="1" cols="10" onKeyUp="onKeyUp()"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="getJSON" />
        </form>

        <div id="result"  class="functions"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajaxSetup ({
                cache: false
            });

            var timer;

            function onKeyUp() {
                stoper();
                timer = setTimeout ( $("#getJSONForm").submit(), 10000 ); 
            }

            function stoper() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }

            $("#getJSONForm").submit(function(){
                    $("#result").html("hello");
                    return false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But... the forms gets submitted at every `onKeyUp` event it seems. It does not wait for the timer to reach the specified 10,000 milliseconds.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first parameter to `setTimeout()` needs to be a function object (or a string, but you should not use that). Like this:

```
timer = setTimeout(function () {
   $("#getJSONForm").submit();
}, 10000);
```

You are currently passing the value of `$("#getJSONForm").submit()` to `setTimeout()`, which is probably not what you want.

Besides that, i would recommend using jQuery's event handling instead of HTML arguments. It is way more elegant, flexible and easier to maintain. You can do it like this:

```
$('#getJSONForm textarea').keyup(function () {
   // the content of your onKeyUp() function goes here
});
```

Have a look at [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) on this topic.